# Remove border buttons for JavaFX primary stage

Tags: java, javafx

**UPDATE: Please, don't close as duplicate. It isn't. Still haven't got answer on my question**

I need to create main application window without resize ability, use this code for primary stage creation

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setPadding(new Insets(25, 80, 50, 80));
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

and see this window

[image]

How can I remove minimize and maximize buttons at all?

I tried to use this line

`primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

but got exception

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set modality for the primary stage`

P.S. I don't want to use `StageStyle.UTILITY` or `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` for primary stage. I need to have standard window decoration with standard close button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    //remove window decoration
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Comment: I need to have standard window decoration with close button.

Comment: What did you mean with standart window ,do you mean fixed style for several OS ? or just custom stage with close button ?